# java MongoDb exception Bad return type

Tags: java, mongodb, intellij-idea

I am new to mongoDB , when trying to do some tutorial with IntellijIDEA & Java1.8.0   , I get this exception which I couldn't find any solution for it

> Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
>   java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type

The simple code I just used is:

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;



public class ConnectToDB {

public static void main( String args[] ) {

    // Creating a Mongo client
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );

    // Creating Credentials
    MongoCredential credential;
    credential = MongoCredential.createCredential("sampleUser", "myDb",
            "password".toCharArray());
    System.out.println("Connected to the database successfully");

    // Accessing the database
    MongoDatabase database = mongo.getDatabase("myDb");
    System.out.println("Credentials ::"+ credential);
}
}
```

and the exception detailes :

```
INFOS: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017 java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type Exception Details:   Location:
    com/mongodb/connection/InternalStreamConnection.translateReadException(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)Lcom/mongodb/MongoException; @115: areturn   Reason:
    Type 'com/mongodb/MongoInternalException' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/mongodb/MongoException' (from method signature)   Current Frame:
    bci: @115
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/mongodb/connection/InternalStreamConnection', 'java/lang/Throwable' }
    stack: { 'com/mongodb/MongoInternalException' }   Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2bc1 0046 9900 082b c000 46b0 2bc1 009d
    0x0000010: 9900 12bb 009e 5912 9f2a b700 5a2b b700
    0x0000020: a0b0 2bc1 00a1 9900 11bb 0076 5912 a22b
    0x0000030: c000 a1b7 0078 b02b c100 a399 0011 bb00
    0x0000040: 7659 12a2 2bc0 00a3 b700 78b0 2bc1 0095
    0x0000050: 9900 12bb 00a4 5912 a52a b700 5a2b b700
    0x0000060: a6b0 2bc1 00a7 9900 0ebb 0099 5912 a82b
    0x0000070: b700 9bb0 2bc1 0075 9900 0ebb 0099 5912
    0x0000080: a92b b700 9bb0 bb00 9959 129c 2bb7 009b
    0x0000090: b0                                        Stackmap Table:
    same_frame(@12)
    same_frame(@34)
    same_frame(@55)
    same_frame(@76)
    same_frame(@98)
    same_frame(@116)
    same_frame(@134)

    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionFactory.create(InternalStreamConnectionFactory.java:45)   at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:114)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

could you please help me in solving that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, based to what you wrote I would like for you to check some basic things:

1) Is the driver version compatible with your mongo version;

2) The connection to mongo is made at very the moment you create MognoClient instance. In your case, the creds are pointless, since you are creating them after trying to estabilish connection with db. Pass your creds to mongo client.

Comment: the problem was that I used an old driver , changing the driver fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

**The VerifyError in Java**

The Java Virtual Machine (JVM) contains a bytecode verifier that is responsible to verify all bytecode before it is executed. The purpose of the bytecode verifier is to verify the integrity of a sequence of bytecodes. The verification procedure consists mostly of the following checks:

> Branches point to valid locations.
>
> Data is initialized and references are type safe.
>
> Access to private, or package private, data and methods is controlled.

The first two checks occur when a class is loaded and made eligible for use, while the third check takes place dynamically, when data items or methods of a class are first accessed by another class.

make sure all these 3 points dont have any error in it

in your case

try this

```
String user; // the user name
 String database; // the name of the database in which the user is defined
 char[] password; // the password as a character array
 // ...

 MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(user, database, password);



 MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("host1", 27017),
                                           Arrays.asList(credential)) ;
```

remember if you have defined credentials here you also need to define it in your db by creating username and password for that particular db

Comment: Thanks for this information , 
but could you please tell me hw that can be fixed?

Comment: what I am trying to do is a simple connection to Mongo DB which is the very basic tutorial, I am stuck there